# Can't calculate total price > 30

Tags: mysql

[image]

For the order items table, get the items for order #6 where the total price is greater than 30

```
USE sql_store;

{ SELECT order_id, product_id,quantity, unit_price,
quantity*unit_price AS total_price

FROM order_items
WHERE order_id = 6 AND total_price > 30

}
```

ERROR CODE:

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include the `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` as TEXT and the actual error code by editing question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karl was nearly right;

```
SELECT order_id
     , product_id
     , quantity
     , unit_price
     , quantity*unit_price subtotal
  FROM order_items 
 WHERE order_id = 6 
   AND quantity*unit_price > 30
```

You could also say `HAVING subtotal > 30`, but this would be less efficient

Comment: Why there is a duplication of command quantity*unit_price ... Why we can't use subtotal in where clause ....

Answer (score 0):

put the math expression in parenthesis:

```
SELECT order_id, product_id,quantity, unit_price, (quantity*unit_price)
FROM order_items 
WHERE order_id = 6 AND (quantity*unit_price) > 30
```

Comment: That is right, but what if i need to add another column as total_price instead of quantity*unit_price in an output window

Comment: sorry but i dont quite get "f i need to add another column as total_price", do you want to programatically fill-in some value in that new column in your DB? or you just want to use "total_price" as an Alias just for this query?

Comment: Wanted to use total_price as an Alias and wanted an output as new column in database

Comment: you can do: (quantity*unit_price AS total_price) and then WHERE order_id = 6 AND total_price > 30, NOTE: that it will not actually create physical NEW column in your database table, but allows you to use it as a "virtual" returned column

Comment: I don't see the relevance of the parentheses

Comment: @Strawberry, thats to isolate an expression independently

Comment: Independent from what?

Comment: Why there is a duplication of command quantity*unit_price ... Why we can't use subtotal in where clause ....